# How to conditionally execute jQuery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form (similar to shown below) which is being validated by jQuery validate plugin -

#### JQuery Form Validation

```
$("#form").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        Field1: {
            required: true,
            field1condition: true
        },
        Field2: {
            required: true,
            field2condition: true
        }
    }
    ,
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        submit(form)
    }
});
```

I need this entire form to be validated ONLY if certain button (let's say `id="clickme"`) has been clicked earlier. But in any case, the form should be submitted (so if the button was clicked then validate and submit else don't run validate and only submit). I can use `depends:` for each field but it seems like a cumbersome task as I have a lot of conditions for every field. Is there any  simpler way to achieve this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (so if the button was clicked then validate and submit else don't run validate and only submit)  Is there any simpler way to achieve this functionality?

YES.

Use `class="cancel"` on the `submit` button.

```
<input type="submit" class="cancel" ....
```

OR

```
<button type="submit" class="cancel" ....
```

Using `class="cancel"`, this button will submit the form as per the plugin's `submitHandler` and bypass the form validation entirely.  Without `class="cancel"`, this button would trigger validation and only submit when the form is fully validated.

I suppose you could *dynamically* add/remove this `cancel` class on a single form `submit` button based on some other action, function or button.

---

---

**BTW:**

Your `submitHandler` is probably superfluous...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    submit(form)
}
```

I only say "probably" because I'm not sure if you have another function named `submit()` or if you're simply improperly using jQuery `.submit()`.

However, this is more like what the plugin is doing by default...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $(form).submit(); // <- default form action
}
```

If that's the case, then you do not even need the `submitHandler` option, since that is already the default behavior of the plugin.  Simply remove the `submitHandler`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. This works for me nicely. Thanks a lot! And yes, I have a submit() function available.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable `_validate`

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    var _validate = false;

    //You need to initialize validate before.
    $("#form").validate({
        debug: true,
        rules: {
            Field1: {
                required: true,
                field1condition: true
            },
            Field2: {
                required: true,
                field2condition: true
            }
        }
        ,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            submit(form)
        }
    });

    $("#clickme").click(function(){
        _validate = true;
    });


    $("#submit_button_click_id").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(_validate) $("#form").validate();
    else $("#form").submit();
    });
 });
```

Comment: That's cumbersome and it will not work.  The `.validate()` method is only use for *initializing* the plugin and will do nothing when called within your conditional handler.